# Sitecore - dynamically rendering a view/controller rendering using rendering reference

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sitecore

i need to render an item dynamically on a different page.
So i have retrieved the Rendering references of item and using the rendering item id and data source.

I could render the item of type "Controller rendering", but not for "view rendering".

```
@Html.Sitecore().Rendering(renderingItem.RenderingID.Guid.ToString(), new  {DataSource = renderingItem.Settings.DataSource, Cacheable = false, Cache_VaryByData = false});

**Exception Message**: Attempt to retrieve context object of type 'System.Web.Mvc.ViewContext' from empty stack.

**Stack Trace**:   at Sitecore.Mvc.Common.ContextService.Peek[T]()
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.GetHtmlHelper()
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Render(Renderer renderer, TextWriter writer, RenderRenderingArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Process(RenderRenderingArgs args)
   at (Object , Object[] )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline[TArgs](String pipelineName, TArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Helpers.SitecoreHelper.RenderRendering(Rendering rendering)
   at Castle.Proxies.Invocations.SitecoreHelper_RenderRendering_1.InvokeMethodOnTarget()
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed()
   at Jabberwocky.Autofac.Extras.MiniProfiler.Interceptors.AsyncProfilingInterceptor.Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed()
   at Castle.Proxies.CustomSitecoreHelperProxy.RenderRendering(Rendering rendering)
   at Castle.Proxies.Invocations.SitecoreHelper_Rendering_1.InvokeMethodOnTarget()
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed()
   at Jabberwocky.Autofac.Extras.MiniProfiler.Interceptors.AsyncProfilingInterceptor.Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed()
   at Castle.Proxies.CustomSitecoreHelperProxy.Rendering(String pathOrId, Object parameters)
```

Comment: How do you render item of type Controller rendering

Answer (score 1):

I recently came across with same issue in my case I have created a custom MVC route and there I need to render all the renderings of Item.

I was having the same issue where Controller rendering was working but View Rendering was not So I made a code change to handle the same. I added a condition to check the rendering type and on the bases of that I have added some custom code to render both.

```
 if (rendering.RenderingItem.InnerItem["Path"] == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(rendering.RenderingItem.InnerItem["Path"]))
            {
                PipelineService.Get().RunPipeline<RenderRenderingArgs>("mvc.renderRendering", new RenderRenderingArgs(rendering, writer));
            }
            else
            {
                ViewData.Model = rendering.Model;
                var viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(controllerContext, rendering.RenderingItem.InnerItem["Path"]);
                var viewContext = new ViewContext(controllerContext, viewResult.View,
                                             ViewData, TempData, writer);
                viewContext.ViewBag.renderingUniqueId = rendering.UniqueId;
                viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, writer);
            }
```

This solution works for me.

may be it can help someone and save some time.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried to use `@Html.Sitecore().ViewRendering("path to rendering")` instead?

Comment: This could have been a comment

Comment: this method doesn't allow for passing in rendering parameters

Comment: rendering parameters were not mentioned as part of the question